# Render Json with methods and several objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, methods

On Rails I can render some json with extra method like this:

```
render json: {
  user: user
}, methods: :photo_url
```

It work's fine! But, I need put more objects in this json that don't has the photo_url method.

```
render json: {
  brand: brand,
  user: user
}, methods: :photo_url
```

I got this error:

> undefined method 'photo_url' for brand

So, How can I insert this method only to user object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making json in controller,you should try the same in a `model`..Check a sample code below,i have added a simple url...with `routes` too.
Also make use of [**url_helpers**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#module-ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor-label-URL+generation+for+named+routes) to add routes in json file.

```
###a part of create action in controller=>USERS_CONTROLLER.RB
    ##code is wrapped in respond_to block
    @new_picture = @hall.pictures.new(:picture=>pic,:title=> "Test")
    if @new_picture.save
        format.json { render json: {files: [@new_picture.to_fileupload_success] }}
    end

###return json from model=>USER.RB/PICTURE.RB
def to_fileupload_success
 {
      "name" => read_attribute(:picture_file_name),
      "size" => read_attribute(:picture_file_size),
      "url" =>  picture.expiring_url.to_s,
      "thumbnailUrl" => picture.expiring_url.to_s,
      "success" => "Picture uploaded",
      "showeUrl" => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.user_picture_path(self)

    }
end
```

HOPE IT HELPS :)

Comment: Great! Thanks! :D
Let the json in controller bothers me. I'll move it to model, it will be so beautiful! :D